# Python list populate, and remove item in while loop

Tags: python, list

I am receiving ID's from a transmission, from different devices. I am placing those ID's into a list with a while.  Populating the list is easy, but I would like to set a timer for if one of the transmitters stops transmitting for a time x, I would like to remove that ID from the list.

To build this list I have:

```
tags_list = []

    while True:
    #######################################################################################
    #FOR CHECK IN THREAD
    #######################################################################################     

    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select([sock], [], [], 1.0)
    if readable:
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        tag_address = ':'.join('%02x' % ord(c) for c in data[12:6:-1])          
        if len(data) == 41:
            if tag_address in valid_tags:
                if len(tags_list) > 0:
                    if tag_address not in wander_tags:
                            tags_list.append(tag_address)
                else:
                    print "ERROR"
```

But I cannot come up with a way to effectively remove an ID from the list when it is not received.  Any ideas? tag_address is formatted xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

Edited to remove "list" as name of the list.

Comment: Create a 2 cell list to hold the `ID` and the `lasTimeTransmitted`.  Add an else to your if to update the ID if it is already in the list with the new `lastTimeTransmitted`. Nest a loop to check each item in the list to see if lastTimeTransmitted+purgeTime < currentTime, remove items that are due to be removed.

Comment: Also, your loop `while True` will never end. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Also, avoid overloading the `list` keyword. Use something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a dict.

```
import time

transmitted_IDs = {}
while True:     
    to_delete = []
    ID = data[1:4]      
        if ID not in transmitted_IDs:
            transmitted_IDs[ID] = time.time()
    for ID, time_taken in transmitted_IDs.iteritems():
        ## Iterating over a dict, we get key, value pairs
        ## So here time_taken is transmitted_IDs[ID] 
        if time.time() - time_taken >= x:
            to_delete.append[ID]
    for ID in to_delete:
        del transmitted_IDs[ID]
```

You can use `transmitted_IDs.keys()` instead of wherever you're using `list` in other places in the code now.

Comment: I tried using your answer, and received the following error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea, as Casey Falk mentioned yesterday, to reuse the name of a built-in (You were using `list`).

Comment: But regardless, that error is popping up because in your usage, `list` is a `Python List` and not a `Dict`. Make sure that first line `transmitted_IDs = {}` is there.

Comment: Yes, my list name is not actually list, and did what is mentioned above, but I ran into another issue as the ID is not an integer, so it was throwing another error for that as well.

Comment: Where does `ID` have to be an integer? `Dict`s will take pretty much anything as a key or a value...

Comment: I have this working nearly perfect now, except when the delete operation happens, it gives a run time error.  I understand that as you are looping you can't change the dict you are working through.  How do you get around this?

Comment: Try it now, I've fixed that.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks for all your time and input.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the rest of your code all I could say is you need to keep track of the last transmission time/ID somewhere, make a copy of `list` (it's bad idea to remove things form a sequence you are currently iterating over) excluding any elements where `time_now - last_transmission_time > timeout_value` and then replace `list` with the copy.

So something like:

```
def clean_list(lst):
    return [ele for ele in lst if ele.last_transmission - time_now < timeout_value]

while True:
    ID = data[1:4]      
    if ID not in id_list:
       id_list.append(ID)
    id_list = clean_list(id_list)
```

I'm using dot notation for clarity and ease of use but you would have to make this work for your setup.

Comment: Don't overload `list` pleeeeease. It huuuuurts.

Comment: @CaseyFalk I know but I'm just using the name he used for clarity. Hopefully he isn't using that as an actual name.

Comment: O-okay... * crawls back into cave where everything has helpful variable names *

Comment: @CaseyFalk If only we lived in such a world. My favorites are SO questions with 13 variables and they are named `x`, `y`, `xx`, `n` and so on ;-).

Comment: Eee! Stop, precious! It burns us!